# gradient() function not working with images

Tags: matlab

I have a quick question. I'm trying to compute an images 2D gradient using the `gradient()` function in MATLAB, but its not working. Specifically, here's my code (The image I'm using is grayscale):

`im = imread('C:\yosemite1.bmp');
g = FindImageGradients(im);`

I get the following error:

> ??? Error using ==> rdivide Integers
>   can only be combined with integers of
>   the same class, or scalar doubles.
>
> Error in ==> gradient at 75
>         g(2:n-1,:) = (f(3:n,:)-f(1:n-2,:))./h(:,ones(p,1));

Any clues on how to solve this ?

Answer (score 2):

Your image data is probably being read as integers in the range [0,255] (for 8 bit per color channel), so the type of `im` is `uint8` or other int type. Try converting it to `single` or `double`:

```
g = FindImageGradients(single(im));
```